# Migrating from a Class A network to a Class C network

Tags: networking

In broad terms, how can one safely to transition from a Class A (10.x.x.x) to Class C network?  We have a gateway for the internet, and a separate local DNS and DHCP server, in this setup.

Comment: First, stop using terms like "Class A" and "Class C". There haven't been such things for over 20 years.

Comment: Second, we need far more information about exactly what you're trying to acheive.

Comment: What are your dhcp lease times, and what kind of dhcp server do you have?

Comment: Also, what kind of gateway/firewall, and does the new range overlap at all with the old range?

Comment: Not sure on the downvotes... clearly this is a question that answerable (I answered it), and it was fun to answer. I guess it could be too opinion-based?

Comment: @MichaelHampton, I appreciate your comment, do you have a source I can go to for more info?  (Randomly searching about IP addresses, subnets, networking, etc. gives lots of sources that still refer to these classes, like http://www.faqs.org/docs/linux_network/x-087-2-issues.ip-addresses.html and https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc940018.aspx and http://www.linux.org/threads/tcp-ip-classless-inter-domain-routing-cidr.4783/ .

Comment: @fukawi2 maybe so, but your comment did not seem to specify what information exactly...

Comment: @JoelCoel, about a month, and `isc-dhcpd-4.1.1-P1`.  Gateway is a COTS router.  The new range wouldn't overlap...despite my apparently poor terminology, I didn't think the ranges *could* overlap in this situation.

Comment: Hm. The first is a 1990s-era book, the second is an article from 2000 which explicitly states that the information is historical, and the third guy is one of the people spreading bad information all over the place. You definitely should be aware that these things used to be a thing, but if you see someone actually using them as if they are still relevant, it is a strong indicator against them.

Comment: The downvotes are for lack of research, and possibly lack of relevant details (the network being transitioned to would help here, as the answer doesn't include the case of 10.x.x.x to 10.1.x.x, for example, but its not clear from the question that that's not the case). This question is meant to be general, sure, but there is plenty of good information out there on this topic already. E.g. http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=1129621

Comment: @MichaelHampton, true, but still to be found--I, at least, was under the impression they were still current because nothing had changed.  I'll ask again, could you point me to a resource that explains the change and rationale for it?  Thanks...

Comment: @Kev See RFC 1517, 1518 and 1519 (September 1993). Note that these have been obsoleted and the current version is RFC 4632. But the historic documents will contain an explanation of the rationale and original architecture you asked for.

Comment: @MichaelHampton thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for...c.f. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing .  Not sure how I went through my whole life so far without putting these pieces together...I guess old misinformation dies hard sometimes!

Comment: while you are at it don't forget to develop an IPV6 strategy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before I get started, the following process assumes you are moving to a whole new IP range that does not overlap with the existing range. If the ranges overlap, you have a whole other set of issues to worry about.

1. On your existing dhcp server scope, turn the lease time down to something relatively short... say, 8 hours or less, so you can do the cut-over overnight.
2. Wait for one complete cycle of your old dhcp lease times, so nothing is left on the network with a long lease.

---

#### While you are waiting for the leases to expire...

3. Plan a maintenance window/down time for the cutover for after the lease expirations, and communicate this out to your users
4. Check each of the devices on your existing network that have static IPs, and create a map (likely in a spreadsheet) to assign them a new IP in the new range.
5. Look for applications on your network that may be configured to connect to a specific IP (LDAP lookups to an Active Directory server, ODBC data sources, and database connection strings are common examples) and create a log for each client that will need to have the application updated.
6. Create a 2nd scope on your dhcp server for the new IP range that is initially disabled. Any full-featured dhcp service will support this, but if you're using something like a consumer/home wireless router, the easiest plan is probably just to buy a new router that you can set up with the new range on an isolated network.
7. Add reservations or an exclusion range to the new dhcp scope for your new static IP addresses, and set the scope to hand out the new address for your gateway and dns servers, as well as any other dhcp option you use.
8. Add a route for your new IP range on each layer-3 device as appropriate (like a router, core switch, or gateway/firewall appliance). Some devices will pick this up automatically, so only do this where you already needed to define a static route for the old range. Adding a route for the new range shouldn't break the old range (as long as they don't overlap), so at this point things are still online.

---

#### Once the leases have expired and renewed with the shorter times, and you are ready to cut over to the new range...

9. Update your DNS server to point each static A record to the new IP. Local devices will have addresses cached, so very little will be immediately broken. However, *from here on out you're on the clock, because some DNS lookups will start to return new addresses that are not yet valid, meaning things can be broken.*
10. Disable the old scope and activate the new scope. If you had to buy a new consumer router, now is the time to swap it out. Like with step 9, most devices already have an address and so won't be broken right away, but you still want to be moving quickly to avoid excessive downtime.
11. Update your gateway/firewall for any port forwards, NAT policies, or other rules that use addresses from the old range.
12. Go through your IP map from step 4 and update the configuration on each of those devices to use the new IP, subnet mask, gateway, and DNS server.
13. Go through the log from step 5 and update the configuration of any client that needs to change a manually configured IP.
14. Test, test some more, troubleshoot the one or two things that always go wrong, test again, and test some more
15. Reboot or push a script to do a release/renew and DNS flush to as many devices as possible, to get them to throw away old leases and old cached DNS addresses.

---

#### Once you are sure everything is working...

16. Document your new settings and static IPs, if you haven't already
17. Remove all references to the old IP range, including routes and the disabled dhcp scope.

Comment: Don't forget about researching and migrating application configurations, or your users will be very unhappy!

Comment: Good point. I've figured things would do DNS lookups, but if you have an applications configured to connect to specific IP addresses, you'll need to update those client configurations as well.